# How to use useState hook in React correctly?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am a little bit confused with using useState() hook in React.
I want to store some data in component state, for example values from form - name, minValue and maxValue. What my code should look like?

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
   name: '',
   minValue: 0,
   maxValue: 9
});
```

or

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [minValue, setMinValue] = useState(0);
const [maxValue, setMaxValue] = useState(9);
```

Is any of these approaches better or are they equal?

Comment: both approach will work but the 1st one is better , so we can mutate all the state variable with one function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While both will work, I would consider the second one to be better, since it is easier to read and update. If you want to handle more complex objects, take a look at [`useReducer()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer).

Comment: Also, it is more idiomatic according to the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables)

Answer (score 0):

The **useState()** returns your current state value and a method to update this state value. There you can set any kind of object, array or string etc. 
Like this:

```
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState('something')
```

To manipulate the state you have to call a function like so:

```
const someFunction = () => { setSomeState('new state') }
```

Hope that helpes.